# What does this expression means 限りなく白に近いグレー in this context ? (crime scene investigation theme)

Tags: meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

**Although i do know white/black colors in Japanese meant innocent/ guilty, I'm not sure about the meaning of this expression "限りなく白に近いグレー ". Hope someone can correct my understanding if i was wrong (my guess: "I guess your case isn't 100% white/innocent yet, it's rather extremely grey to me..")**

Context: MC got arrested by a police officer, since she suspected him had assaulted a naked girl (though MC got a head injury and got an amnesia /temporal memory loss- so he didn't remember any thing). But after interrogated MC, she considers that he's innocent and let him go home. But MC said he's still not sure if he had committed a crime or not. This is what the police officer said to him after the interrogation.

MC「でも、あの子は裸だったし」

Police「そうね。で、その服はどこに？」

MC「えーっと……」

そういえば、服はどこにあったんだ？

もしも俺が服を剥い……じゃなくて、脱がせていたとしたら、近くに女の子の着ていた服が落ちていたはず。

しかし、そんなものはなかった。

見落としていただけの可能性はあるが、だとしたら俺が去った後に少女は服を着てから追いかけてきてるはず。

全裸のままだったのはどう考えても不自然だ。

**Police「状況的には、限りなく白に近いグレーかなぁ」**

MC「はぁぁぁ……」

クソデカいため息が漏れた。

MC「脅かさないでくださいよ！シロ濃厚とわかってたなら、逮捕しなくてもよかったじゃないですか！」

Police「シロクロわかんないなら捕まえといたほうが安全」

MC「そうかもしれないですけど……はあ、無駄に緊張した」

Police「さあ、そろそろお帰り。自分の家の場所は覚えてる？」

MC「まったく覚えてないです」

Answer (score 3):

クロ and シロ are originally police jargon meaning "guilty" and "innocent", respectively. グレー means "suspicious".

- https://jisho.org/word/%E7%99%BD
- https://jisho.org/word/%E9%BB%92

In your case, "extremely gray" is a mistranslation because 限りなく is an adverbial form and thus modifies (白に)近い, not グレー. 限りなく白に近いグレー refers to gray that is very close to white. In other words, 99% innocent.